# Sweet Alert not displaying but response message is showing but opens in new browser . how can i solve this?

Tags: javascript, django

this is the  html code for form

```
{% extends 'frontend/master/master.html' %}

{% block content %}


<h1>contact page</h1>
<hr>
<form action="" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
    {{my_form}}
    <br>
<button id="send_mail_ajax" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

code from custom.js everything is working fine but when i want to show the json response from django library it opens in new tab

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#send_mail_ajax').on('click', function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              let sender = $('#id_sender').val();
              let subject = $('#id_subject').val();
              let message = $('#id_message').val();
              let data = { sender: sender, subject: subject, message: message };
              $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
                 data: data,
                 csrftoken= jQuery("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
                 success: function (response) {
                    Swal.fire(
                       'Mail',
                       response.message,
                       'success'
                     )
                 }
              })
           });
        });
```

code from views.py
i tried to use @csrf_exempt from decorators library also but it showed 403 forbidden.

```
def contact(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      sender = request.POST.get('sender')
      subject = request.POST.get('subject')
      message = request.POST.get('message')
      send_mail(subject, message, sender, ['razeevstha002@gmail.com'])
      resData = dict()
      resData['message'] = "Successfully Send"
      return JsonResponse(resData)
   else:
      data = {
         'my_form':ContactForm
      }
      return render(request, 'frontend/pages/contact/contact2.html',data)
```

Comment: Can you add the `<form>` HTML?

Comment: {% extends 'frontend/master/master.html' %}

{% block content %}


<h1>contact page</h1>
<hr>
<form action="" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
    {{my_form}}
    <br>
<button id="send_mail_ajax" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}

Comment: you can add form.html to the question. it will be more understandable.

Comment: I added the html code for form